# Graph library to draw An electronic truck logbook data

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart, android-graphview

I need to draw a graph like below image 
[image: Electronic logbook data]

I know I can draw this with line chart but I need that frame. Each slot is divided into 4 another small slot just like **Meter Scale**. Actually, I need the background grid like this image graph or like meter scale. I have used [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). This library doesn't more that 25 label count and I think this library doesn't support this kind of frame. Help me to find a library for drawing this kind of graph in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Custom View will be the last approach if i don't get any library

Comment: want grid like that

Comment: not blue red line just grid (each slot divided into sub slot)

Comment: i am not concern about blue-red line. I am just asking is any library support such kind for grid . If any library support this then i don't need to spend lot of time for doing it. If not then i have to implement it of my own.

Comment: it is off-topic tu ask for a library here.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look into this library, [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/)
You can make grids in graph using

```
RectF rect = plot.getGraph().getGridRect();

plot.setDomainStep(StepMode.INCREMENT_BY_PIXELS, 3);
plot.setRangeStep(StepMode.INCREMENT_BY_PIXELS, 3);
plot.getGraph().getDomainGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.RED);
plot.getGraph().getRangeGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

and there's also zoom functionality for graph where you should override the function and set this graph pixels accordingly and redraw it